# triviality of tensor product of vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-topology

Let $\xi$ be a $O(n)$-bundle with fibre $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $\xi\otimes \mathbb{C}$, $\xi\otimes \mathbb{H}$ be complex vector bundles and quaternionic vector bundles.

If $\xi$ is not a trivial bundle, can we obtain $\xi\otimes \mathbb{C}$, $\xi\otimes \mathbb{H}$ are not trivial bundles?

Comment: The question seems strangely phrased. You're asking if, given any non-trivial $O(n)$ bundle (over a space $X$), the complexification will remain non-trivial? In other words, is there a single non-trivial $O(n)$-bundle whose complexification is non-trivial?

Comment: Or perhaps you're just asking whether or not it is always true that given a non-trivial bundle the complexification and quaternionification bundles are non-trivial?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Möbius real line bundle bundle $\xi$ over the circle $S^1$ is not trivial but its complexification $\xi\otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C$ is trivial, like all complex line bundles over  $S^1$.
[This last fact is due to complex line bundles on the circle being classified by $H^2(S^1,\mathbb Z)=0$]

Answer (score 0):

The tangent  Bundle of  sphere is  another example.  For arbitrary  vector  bundle E, it seems that $E\otimes \mathbb{C}$ has a trivial line bundle, as a summand.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209247/almost-complex-structure-and-nontrivial-idempotents

Moreover, I guess that the complexification of canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{R}P^{n}\;\;n>1$ is  nontrivial.